# Synchronise two databases , everytime something changes in DB A , it changes in DB B and vice versa

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, synchronization

I have a database A, I am planning on getting a server in a foreign country and have a similar database to A called B. Everytime something changes (tables , data) in database A, it should also change on B, and vice versa.

Comment: Have you looked up `replication` ?

Comment: Tried refer to [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/synchronize-data?view=sql-server-ver15)